# XPath: exclude text nodes that contains a certain word

Tags: xpath

I have a problem with Xpath. I am trying to find all text nodes of the first iteration of a div but exclude the ones that have a key word in them.

A simple example:

```
<div class="blabla">
  <p>I like bananas</p>
  <p>I also like apples</p>

<div class="blabla">
  <p>some text</p>
```

I want to fetch all text from the first div "blabla" but exclude all paragraphs that contains the word "bananas". In this instance I want only "I also like apples". The number of paragraphs and the placement of the word "bananas" is random.

Here's what I've tried:

```
(//div[@class='blabla'])[1][not(contains(text(), 'bananas'))]
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. If somebody has an idea, it would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to get text nodes from `div` as single string, excluding `p` that contains `"bananas"` or get list of text nodes from each `p` excluding `"bananas"`? Also specify XPath version if you need a solution for specific version

Comment: `(//div[@class='blabla'])[1]/*[not(contains(text(), 'bananas'))]`

Comment: or `(//div[@class='blabla'])[1]/*[not(contains(text(), 'bananas'))]/text()`

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the reference to the `p` child-element before your third predicate:

```
//div[@class='blabla'][1]/p[not(contains(text(), 'bananas'))]
```

It were merely the two letters `/p` which made the difference.